# access vba bombs when defining html results page as variable to extract content from php page

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, scrape

My client is trying to use an access VBA script to send a string to a php page i created, then bring the data that is returned on the page back into his db

i use a mac and cannot run any of the VB code, but here is what i was able to find (two versions), but both bomb in the first dim statement

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim iHTML As HTMLDocument
Dim objHttp As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
set objHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHttp.open "GET", "http://www.bestenergyctri.com/zipcode.php?isValidate=adb&address1=352%20w%2046&address2=&city=new%20york&state=ny&zip5= 
", False
objHttp.send

Set iHTML = objHttp.ResponseText

straddress1 = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("address1").Item(1).innerText
straddress2 = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("address2").Item(1).innerText
strcity = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("City").Item(1).innerText
strstate = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("State").Item(1).innerText
strzip5 = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("Zip5").Item(1).innerText
strzip4 = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("Zip4").Item(1).innerText

SaveWebInfo straddress1, straddress2, strcity, strstate, strzip5, strzip4
Set iHTML = Nothing
Set objHttp = Nothing

End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim iHTML As HTMLDocument
Dim objHttp As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
set objHttp = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
objHttp.open "GET", "http://www.bestenergyctri.com/zipcode.php?isValidate=adb&address1=352%20w%2046&address2=&city=new%20york&state=ny&zip5= 
", False
objHttp.send

Set iHTML = objHttp.ResponseText

straddress1 = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("address1").Item(1).innerText
straddress2 = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("address2").Item(1).innerText
strcity = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("City").Item(1).innerText
strstate = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("State").Item(1).innerText
strzip5 = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("Zip5").Item(1).innerText
strzip4 = iHTML.getElementsByClassName("detect").Item(x - 1).getElementsByClassName("thedata").Item(0).getElementsByClassName("Zip4").Item(1).innerText

SaveWebInfo straddress1, straddress2, strcity, strstate, strzip5, strzip4
Set iHTML = Nothing
Set objHttp = Nothing

End Sub
```

does anyone have any suggestions on how we can get the page properly read into a variable so that it can be parsed

thanks

Comment: "bombs" is not a very useful description of your problem.  In any case, you cannot use this approach on a Mac since it uses COM automation.

Comment: `.Item(x - 1)` - is `x` declared elsewhere in the code? If not, this should produce a "Variable not defined" error as long as you have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module containing this code. If you don't have `Option Explicit` and `x` isn't declared elsewhere then `.Item(x - 1)` is the same as `.Item(-1)` and will fail

Comment: You say both scripts "bomb" (whatever that means, please be crystal clear next time..) on the first Dim. That might indicate that the reference **Microsoft HTML Object Library** was not ticked under Tools -> References (menu option on the Microsoft VBA screen).

Comment: i know 'bombs' is a useless descriptor, however, as i said, i don't have a pc to test on, so i have to pass on the comments from my client, he swore he'd be able to script this, now i am helping make that statement true. i will ask him about the reference libraries. if anyone else has any thoughts that will help him i would appreciate it!

Comment: Was this solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler example using CSS querySelector and avoiding using Hungarian notation

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim iHTML As New HTMLDocument, objHttp As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60 '<== Note this is version specific syntax. 60 is for Excel 2016
    Set objHttp = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    objHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.bestenergyctri.com/zipcode.php?isValidate=adb&address1=352%20w%2046&address2=&city=new%20york&state=ny&zip5=", False
    objHttp.send

    Dim address1  As String, address2 As String, city As String, state As String, zip5 As String, zip4 As String
    With iHTML
        .body.innerHTML = objHttp.ResponseText
        address1 = .querySelector(".address1").innerText
        address2 = .querySelector(".address2").innerText
        city = .querySelector(".City").innerText
        state = .querySelector(".State").innerText
        zip5 = .querySelector(".Zip5").innerText
        zip4 = .querySelector(".Zip4").innerText
    End With

    Debug.Print "Address 1: " & address1
    Debug.Print "Address 2: " & address2
    Debug.Print "City: " & city
    Debug.Print "State: " & state
    Debug.Print "Zip5: " & zip5
    Debug.Print "Zip4: " & zip4
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image: Example output]

**References added to VBA > Tools > References:**

[image: References]

*Last two references are the important ones.

Comment: No worries. Let me know how it goes and if does answer please remember to accept as answer to stop this question from re-surfacing. Happy to clarify further details as well.

Comment: thanks! so you didn't like the bizarre html references, lol! but i do have a further question, he tried to run it, but he can't find in access where he adds the tools>>references - any thoughts on what i can tell him? and thanks again

Comment: Press Alt + F11 when inside of Access to open the Visual Basic Editor then Tools > References....